# JavaScript - Desktop app with database (no server)

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, electron

I am currently aiming to create a very small scale desktop application which would feature retrieving data based on a simple search (keyword) and reflect static data linked to it. Some numbers to put it in perspective:

- About 150-200 "key" values
- About 5-10 values to be displayed per "key" value
- Editable (although the info tends to remain same most of time - maybe
  1 or 2 amendments/month in total on all data stored)
- Data should be amendable by 1 privileged user. (so I would have a DB with users & one with the information)

An example:
Cards you see when you do a simple google search. For example you search for an actor (key value) and your query generates a "card" with values (age, length, wage, brothers,...).

All data would be stored on the same drive alongside the app, so there should be no server interaction whatsoever. In **python** I was using SQLite to achieve this. However I wanted to make a sleek desktop app using the **Electron** framework which uses JavaScript.

I'm not extremely familiar with JS and Node.JS and the likes, so I am polishing up my knowledge and am reading a lot on how to use databases with JS, but I can't seem to find a concrete solution.

So my questions:

1. Is it possible to have a SQLite3 kind of database locally with the
   app (same drive) controlled via JavaScript?
2. Or perhaps is there a possibility to have JavaScript communicate
   with Python and do the database operations with Python?

I am familiar how to use Python to interact with SQLite, however I've not yet touched interaction between different languages (in this case JavaScript to Python & vice versa).

I would very much appreciate it if somebody could point me in the right direction or which area I should look at.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create an Electron App based on the quite powerful SQLite3 bindings [available at npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3).